# Synchronize reads and writes to TCP socket

Tags: sockets, go, read-write

I'm trying to communicate with a TCP server which responds to messages:

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "log"
)

func handleErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main() {

    // connect
    host := "1.2.3.4:5678"
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host)
    handleErr(err)
    defer conn.Close()

    // write to socket
    message := "Test\n"
    conn.Write([]byte(message))

    // read from socket
    // (assume response is 'Test\n')
    reply := make([]byte, 1024)
    conn.Read(reply)
    log.Println(string(reply))

}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to send a message to the socket-server on the other end, wait for a response and then process it. I seem to be having trouble with properly syncing these write/read operation to be timed correctly - right now the read action seems to block the write; I'm assuming this happens due to the async nature of Go. What's an idiomatic way to do this? Is it goroutines? A continuous `for { .. }` loop for the reader? A `sync.Wait` mechanism? Help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work should work just fine. Golang is dead simple, there is no need for thinking about synchronizing read/write calls.

[EDIT] To be clear: Go's networking model is synchronous, just like any old style socket program. Go uses internally efficient tricks to deal with it but as a programmer you have the comfort to program sequential code, which is the whole point about goroutines. Goroutines can be like threads but they are so cheap that you can create a LOT of them (a.k.a. [*fibers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29)).

Keep in mind that TCP might not send every piece in one shot. You should always check the return values to be sure that everything has been sent. Maybe the server just receives a part of the message and waits for more, but your client is already waiting for an answer? Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks - this ended up working, turned out this was a server issue. Just out of curiosity, how would you mix in goroutines here and still keep the functionality? Would a good use case is when I have a lot of simultaneous messages to send and read replies for?

Comment: Goroutines comes in handy if you want to do things concurrently. Your example is quite good, another usage would be a web crawler. But really think about goroutines in terms of threads. I know they are not threads, but kind of green threads. Another nice example would be a web server. Every request starts in a new goroutine. So you can handle all incoming requests concurrently without using one os-thread per connection or fiddle with callback-hell based approaches. It enables you to code like in the 90' but you get all the performance from epoll, kqueue, iocp, etc. It's just awesome :)

Comment: And also keep in mind that almost all methods in goland are blocking, so the method does not continue when, for instance, Write() has not finished. You have the nice happen-before thing here =)

Comment: Great reasoning, I appreciate it!